# C# ConvertAll syntax

Tags: c#, convertall

I'm trying to understand the syntax for ConvertAll in C#, and despite looking at several examples and trying to copy them, I can't get the following line containing s2 to compile; VSE2013 says

> "Error    1   No overload for method 'ConvertAll' takes 1 arguments   ".

what does the error message mean? Where am I going wrong?  And yes, I understand that Select is much better to use in these situations, for several reasons.  Thanks!

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine ("jello world");

    int s1 = args.Sum(st => int.Parse(st));
    int s2 = args.ConvertAll(x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();
    int s3 = args.Select(st => int.Parse(st)).Take(2).Sum();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `ConvertAll` on an actual array *instance* - but [`ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a static method, hence does not have access to the content of your array - you need to pass in the array itself as the first parameter so that it can use it - and since it's a static method should call it on the `Array` class itself:

```
int s2 = Array.ConvertAll(args, x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();
```

Also shorter using a method group:

```
int s2 = Array.ConvertAll(args, int.Parse).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `args.ConvertAll(x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();` to `Array.ConvertAll(args, x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();`.

As the error message told you, 'ConvertAll' does not take 1 argument, so that should clue you in to the fact that you need more arguments (in this case, the array).

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for proper usage of Array.ConvertAll.

Comment: Thanks for your comments; I had already found that syntax, but there are numerous examples out there showing the form int[] s2 = args.ConvertAll (delegate converter ) ; is that deprecated now ?

Comment: Are you sure those examples weren't with lists, rather than arrays? That is the proper syntax for lists. See the difference in examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You're right, and that was my basic problem:  I thought args was a list, when it was an array.  Thanks!  If I convert it to a list with: List<string> list = args.OfType<string>().ToList(); then I can sum it with int ss = list.ConvertAll<int>(x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!